# Can I use LINQ to do a join on an IQueryable from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two tables. Questions and UserProfile

```
    public QuestionMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.QuestionId);

        this.Property(t => t.Title)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        this.Property(t => t.CreatedBy)
            .IsRequired();
    }

    public UserProfileMap()
    {
        this.HasKey(t => t.UserId);

        this.Property(t => t.UserName)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(56);
    }
```

My repository call looks like this at the moment:

```
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
    {
        return DbSet;
    }
```

Is there a way that I can change the repository call so that it will go to the database, join the Question and UserProfile tables and then bring back a list that has the UserName from the UserProfile table? I realize I may have to create another class (that includes UserName) for the return type and I can do that.

Comment: How these two entities related to each other? `CreatedBy` is a UserProfile?

Comment: CreatedBy is a number that is linked to the UserId in the UserProfile table. What I really want is not to see that number but to see the UserName which is a string.

Comment: Generic repositories, if you decide to use them, should not each have their own context. You'll never be able to compose queries from their `DbSets` any more. They should share one context for one unit of work. But the first question is whether you really need generic repositories on top of EF's built-in repositories (`DbSet`s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't configure property mapping to some field of joined entity. But you can create navigation properties in your Question and UserProfile entites, which will provide joined enitites:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

And add mapping configuration to user mapping:

```
HasMany(u => u.Questions)
    .WithRequired(q => q.CreatedBy)
    .Map(m => m.MapKey("UserId"))
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

Now you will be able to eager load users when querying questions:

```
var questions = context.Questions.Include(q => q.CreatedBy);
foreach(var question in questions)
    Console.WriteLine(question.CreatedBy.UserName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make the join in your controller not your repository. The repository is supposed to deal with only one entity in your database.

Or you can create a View in your database, and add it as an entity to your entity framework model.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, [you CAN join tables using LINQ without navigation properties.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534644%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Let me demonstrate:

```
public class Question
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string TextBody { get; set; }
    public int CreatedBy { get; set; }
}

public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

So that's the (very simple) model. Now, I'm not at all familiar with the `IQueryable<T> GetAll()` method shown in the OP's post, but I'm assuming that this method can be used to return an `IQueryable<Question>` that would, when executed, get all the Questions from the database. In my example, I'm just going to use `MyDbContext` instead, but this could be replaced with your other method if you prefer it...

So the LINQ join would be done as follows:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    var results = MyDbContext.Questions.Join(MyDbContext.UserProfiles,
        q => q.CreatedBy,
        u => u.UserID,
        (q,u) => new {
            q.QuestionID,
            q.Title,
            q.TextBody,
            u.UserName
        });
    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("User {0} asked a question titled {1}:",
            result.UserName, result.Title);
        Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", result.TextBody)
    }
}
```

Now, I do think that navigation properties are MUCH better for such obvious and common relationships. However, there are times when you might not want to add a navigation property for a relationship that is seldom referenced. In those cases, it might just be better to use the `Join` method.